# Configuring QWC2 Web Client in production environment and displaying custom map served by QGIS Server

Tags: qgis-server, qwc2

I have successfully set up a  QGIS Server and can access the default world map when I go to the corresponding url.
I also set up qwc2 using the `qwc2-demo-app` repo and I can access the default map from `myapp.com/qwc`

I would like to display the map that the QGIS Server is serving from the qwc2 web client. I have tried to change the url parameter of the `themes.json` to the url of the QGIS Server URL but it is still displaying the default map published with the qwc2 demo app.

How do I make this web client app serve the QGIS Server map?

Comment: I think you need to run the config-generator

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Ok and this config-generator is found in the app repo?, I ran `yarn run prod` on the demo-app repo to produce the prod folder I am serving qwc from now

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Thank you for pointing out the config-generator. It led me to the answer I have posted.

Comment: I'm happy my comment helped you. I'm sorry I could not help you better since I am not an qwc expert, but "only" a sysadmin. I suggest you accept your answer as the correct solution so that it can be a guide for other people looking for a solution.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek You did well, thank you. I have accepted it as the answer and true that should help others encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning the `qwc2-demo-app` you need to edit the `themesConfig.json` file and add `your-custom-url` that is serving the qgis maps under:

```
"themes":{
        "items":[
            {
                "url":"your-custom-url",
```

and under:

```
"groups":[
            {
                "title":"Dev Tests",
                "items":[
                    {
                        "title": "Demo",
                        "url": "your-custom-url",
```

Determine whether the included `backgroundLayers` and `externalLayers` are relevant for your use case. Include others or remove these objects from the config altogether.

Save `themesConfig.json` and then run `yarn run prod`.

You can now point your webserver to the resulting `prod` directory or copy it to your preferred html root. Make sure to add a location block pointing this directory in your htaccess or nginx conf files.